# How to get total "active" users using Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have four tables:

Table A: users_table

Table B: users_account_table

Table C: fangates_table

Table D: downloads_table

Table A(users_table) contains three columns: ID, NAME and GATE_COUNT.
Table C(fangates_table) contains users gates.
Table D(downloads_table) contains fangates_table_id and account_id.

```
TABLE A
ID  |   NAME    |   GATE_COUNT
---------------------------
1   |   Joy     |   2        
---------------------------
2   |   Ash     |   0
---------------------------
3   |   Nik     |   2
---------------------------
4   |   Wox     |   0

TABLE B
ID  |   A_ID    |   ACCOUNT_ID
---------------------------
1   |   1       |   123456       
---------------------------
2   |   1       |   654321
---------------------------
3   |   3       |   5888
---------------------------
4   |   3       |   8787


TABLE C
ID  |   A_ID    |   TITLE
---------------------------
1   |   1       |   ABCD         
---------------------------
2   |   1       |   DFCV
---------------------------
3   |   3       |   FGTG
---------------------------
4   |   3       |   FRGTG

TABLE D
ID  |   C_ID    |   ACCOUNT_ID
---------------------------
1   |   1       |   123456       
---------------------------
2   |   2       |   123456
---------------------------
3   |   3       |   7859
---------------------------
4   |   1       |   7585
```

From the above tables, I am trying to get the total "active" users (where an active user is defined as a user with fangates having any downloads other not themself)

I have tried the following query, but it has failed.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM D
WHERE (C_ID,ACCOUNT_ID)
NOT IN 
(SELECT C.ID, B.ACCOUNT_ID FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.A_ID 
LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID = C.A_ID
WHERE A.GATE_COUNT >0);
```

Comment: Whats your flag to identify active and inactive users?

Comment: an active users is a user with fan-gates having any downloads in donwloads table but not himself

Answer (score 1):

The error, as I see it, is that you are failing to provide a join parameter in the initial selection of your table. If I am to understand your table design correctly, the following query would retrieve all the information in your tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM A,B,C,D
WHERE B.A_ID = A.ID AND C.A_ID = A.ID AND D.C_ID = C.ID;
```

If my presumption is correct, and you are trying to get the active users, you could simply place your parameters as an appended `AND` and continue onward. However, doing this many joins could greatly slow down any code; joins are a very taxing process, no matter how small the tables are. Since you are looking to find the count of downloads

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM D
WHERE (C_ID)
NOT IN 
(SELECT C.ID FROM A, C 
WHERE GATE_COUNT >0 AND A.ID = C.A_ID);
```

From what I can tell, you don't need to specify the distinct `ACCOUNT_ID` from the B table, as the information is distinctly paired to the B table. Otherwise, your columns would mismatch.

Otherwise, you can do a second lookup and try adding the B lookup as an `AND` parameter

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM D
WHERE (C_ID)
NOT IN (SELECT C.ID FROM A, C 
WHERE GATE_COUNT >0 AND A.ID = C.A_ID) AND ACCOUNT_ID NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT B.ACCOUNT_ID FROM A,B WHERE A.ID = B.A_ID AND A.GATE_COUNT >0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(B.A_ID))
FROM TABLE_B B
JOIN TABLE_C C ON (B.A_ID = C.A_ID)
JOIN TABLE_D D ON (D.C_ID = C.C_ID AND B.ACCOUNT_ID <> D.ACCOUNT_ID)
```